# Is it possible to extend MassTransit RabbitMq transport/pipeline exceptions?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, rabbitmq, masstransit

We are using a clustered setup with HA queues using MassTransit and RabbitMQ. This works mostly well, but is it possible to extend what happens when there is an exception in the transport layer?

For instance, once a node in the cluster goes down a consumer gets this error:

```
MassTransit.Util.TaskSupervisor Error: 0 :
Failed to close scope
 MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Pipeline.RabbitMqBasicConsumer -
 rabbitmq://x:5672/y/z?durable=false&autodelete=true&prefetch=16,
 System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
```

The message flow will still be working as it will switch to another node, but we would like to perform additional actions when the above happens. It is a handled exception, so it is not possible to hook into UnhandledException for the application.